# Properties Validation Failed for AWS CloudFront Distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

Received this error indicated in the[Error in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs9aK.png)

[Image of yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxmzr.png)

I tried researching the issue. Im honestly not sure where to start in diagnosing the issue in logical order.

Comment: Please post code and error as properly formatted code blocks, not screenshots.

Comment: Please avoid providing code blocks, logs and errors through images. Copy and paste them in your question as text, and format them (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) correctly (in order to differentiate them from normal text). Some users might not be able to properly see your images or reproduce a minimal example from these images.

Answer (score 0):

TTL settings should be in [AWS::CloudFront::Distribution CacheBehavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-cachebehavior.html), not directly under `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution`.